# How to open a file using eval that works with '--alternative-editor'

Tags: emacsclient, command-line-arguments

The following command works to open a file in an existing emacs instance:

```
emacsclient --eval \
"(progn (find-file \\"/a/b.txt\\") (goto-line 1) (forward-char 2) (recenter))" \
--no-wait \
--alternate-editor=emacs
```

However when there is no emacs instance running it creates a buffer called `b.txt")`.

Is there a way this can be made to work in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In emacs 26 [this will be supported](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-26&id=98f01a13a3bf2a4db2dcc82a342ee017326de732) by using `--alternate-editor="emacs --eval"`

For now you can write a script that wraps emacs, eg:

`emacs-eval-wrapper`

```
#!/bin/bash
exec emacs --eval "$@"
```